# "Неклен", произношение

Tags: орфоэпия

Узнал, что есть такое дерево *"неклен",* буквально означающее *не клён* (оно маленькое, почти как куст), но произносящееся с ударением на первый слог и соответственно без Ё. Так вот, у нас зашёл спор, как произносится ударное Е. Мне кажется, что твёрдо, а отцу, что мягко. Рассудите кто-нибудь, пожалуйста. Есть тут ботаники или лесники? :))

Добавлю, что согласно тому, что я нашёл о нём в интернете, название пошло из украинского, а там нету мягкого Е. Это, конечно, не значит, что оно не могло стать мягким в русском, но всё же могло оказать влияние.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы же не можем ориентироваться на произношение ботаников и лесников; отличие их произношения от нормативного будет иметь помету "спец.", как *д**О**быча* и *комп**А**с*.

Зато есть словари орфоэпические и ударений - там непременно отмечаются твёрдые и мягкие согласные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А тут - полное молчание, значит, слышится, как пишется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для сравнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, что прав папа.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина!